# Contar y sumar en criteria builder

Tags: java

Bueno esta es mi consulta en criteria builder ya se que esta mal formulada lo que quiero es traer segun el idaprobsum una serie de elementos despues traer las solictudes que estan con ese id despues sumar las cantidades de cada una

```
    public  Aprobacion_solicitud verificalistaaprobaciones(Long idaprobsum) {
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Aprobacion_solicitud> criteria = cb.createQuery(Aprobacion_solicitud.class);
Root<Aprobacion_solicitud> member = criteria.from(Aprobacion_solicitud.class);
        criteria.select(member);
        cb.sum(member.get(Aprobacion_solicitud_.cantidad));
        return em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
    }
```

Comment: Esta es la columna que quieres sumar Aprobacion_solicitud_.cantidad??

Comment: @RaulCacacho si

Comment: Te esta dando algun error? porque yo lo veo bien

Comment: quiero sumar todas las cantidase que estan en la colmnua cantidad sabes como hacer eso ? @RaulCacacho

Comment: Prueba con la respuesta que te puse si no te funciona hay otras maneras de hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falto fue escoger que   `idaprobsum` iba a ir sumando puedes seleccionandolo con un `multipleSelect` hacerlo de esta manera:

```
public  Aprobacion_solicitud verificalistaaprobaciones(Long idaprobsum) {
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Aprobacion_solicitud> criteria = cb.createQuery(Aprobacion_solicitud.class);
Root<Aprobacion_solicitud> member = criteria.from(Aprobacion_solicitud.class);
criteria.select(member);
criteria.multiselect(member.get("idaprobsum"), cb.sum(c.get("cantidad")));
        return em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
 }
```